# Cannot load CSS/JS files in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm getting rather persistent 404 errors when loading Javascript/CSS files located in my wwwroot. [image: Here's my folder structure]

The errors that I get in my console:

```
No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:2155/css/site.css
No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:2155/js/slippy/Core.js
```

Both of which are `404` errors.

Here's the code in my `_Layout.cshtml` file, being included in my `_ViewStart.cshtml` file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/js/slippy/Core.js"></script>
</head>
```

The CSS include is different to show that both are failing.

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET Core so I'm lost as to what could be causing this. I've put in a HTML file into the JS directory to see if it would load, which didn't happen. Can anyone tell me how to get these to include successfully?

Comment: What happens if you navigate directly to `http://localhost:2155/css/site.css` with your browser?

Comment: Also a 404. I moved the CSS/JS files to the root (`localhost:2155/site.css`) which also 404'd.

Comment: What version of MVC is this? Also, on your Program.cs file, do you have this line: `.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`?

Comment: @Brian that line's included yup. MVC `version 1.1.2`.

Comment: Please edit into your question the relevant configuration from Startup.cs where you wire up the static content files to be served up.

Comment: @mason that's fixed it! Forgot to include that. Thanks. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error by removing the `app.UseStaticFiles();` line under Configure in Startup.cs, that should be there with the starter template

Comment: @Brian Hey it wasn't me that fixed it, it was you. I just wanted you to include the configuration so you'd have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't have much experience with ASP.NET Core, but my expectation is that removing that line would break things, not fix them. So I wouldn't feel comfortable putting that as the answer myself until I knew more about what effects it might have.

Comment: @Brian thanks, Mason mentioned it above which has fixed the issue.